# Are there any sports in which a disability is actually an advantage?

Tags: trivia

Per title. I don't know how this would work, but perhaps something like "a person born without arms would have a sleeker aerodynamic profile so they can fly through the air faster/further".

I'm aware that some mental disabilities can lead to an advantage in mental sports - e.g. some people with autism have [amazing memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autism_and_memory#Memory_strengths) but I'm wondering about physical disabilities.

Comment: I've been wondering if there's a link between scoliosis and sprinting https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17449/is-there-any-link-between-scoliosis-and-sprinting

Answer (score -2):

Nascar? (sitting down a lot) or The Paralympic Games.

Not a disability, but sometimes shortness or small stature can be an advantage e.g. Horse Racing jockeys, gymnastics, etc.

Going in the opposite direction, a few famous athletes had/have acromegaly (excess growth hormone) NBA player Pavel Podkolzin, wrestlers Andrew the Giant and the Big Show, etc.

Comment: Voted down by people who don't play sports...